# How to extend ParadoxLabs\Authnetcim\Model\ConfigProvider to add addtional config data to access in authencim.js and related .html template?

Tags: magento2.2

I see following code in authnetcim/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/authnetcim.js. I understand that it's using cc.html template to display the content. How to know which Block or Helper classes are called to get data for use inside this .js and in cc.html template?
I need to check customer session data and display a message around 'Place Order' button, so trying to understand which back-end code needs to be modified, so that I can get that data into HTML template file.

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'ParadoxLabs_TokenBase/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cc'
],
function (ko, Component) {
    'use strict';
    var config=window.checkoutConfig.payment.authnetcim;
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'ParadoxLabs_Authnetcim/payment/cc'
```

Wrote custom Model ConfigProvider.php that extends ParadoxLabs\Authnetcim\Model\ConfigProvider, then added below method

`public function getCustomerName() {
    if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
    }
    return false;
}`

Added below code to getConfig() method:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    if (!$this->methods[static::CODE]->isAvailable()) {
        return [];
    }

    $config             = parent::getConfig();
    $selected           = null;
    $storedCardOptions  = [];


    $config = array_merge_recursive($config, [
        'payment' => [
            static::CODE => [
                'useVault'                => true,
                'canSaveCard'             => $this->canSaveCard(),
                <few other attributes here>
                'canStoreBin'             => $this->getCanStoreBin(),
        'customerName' => $this->getCustomerName(), -- new custom attribute
            ],
        ],
    ]);
$config['customerName'] = $this->getCustomerName();
    return $config;
}
```

`$config['customerName'] = $this->getCustomerName();

Overwrote vendor/paradoxlabs/authnetcim/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/authentcim.js to add new function as below, using requirejs-config.js in my custom module:

`getCustomerName: function () {
    return config.customerName;
}`

Code in cc.html copied from vendor/paradoxlabs/authnetcim/view/frontend/web/template/paymentcc.html template to access customerName data, inside the custom module:

`<!-- ko if: (getCustomerName())-->`

I do see it working if I hard code a name inside the authentcim.js getCustomerName() function, so I am guessing it's an issue with getting model data into config object that is of type window.checkoutConfig.payment.authnetcim.

Comment: Share the code for the js file (vendor/paradoxlabs/authnetcim/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/authentcim.js)

Comment: @AnshuMishra not sure why extending vendor specific ConfigProvider didn't work. I tried your approach at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246902/how-to-pass-data-from-php-to-javascript-component and I now see data in the .js and .html files. I abelive that this approach would add new variable to existing checkoutConfig object and not replace existing data, is that understanding correct?

Comment: yes, that will not replace existing data. Also, avoid using preferences as much as possible, try using plugins, event observers, types and virtual types in di xml

Comment: sure, starting to understand n number ways we can customize Magento 2 behavior, it's bit overwhelming for new folks. Do you recommend any good book or site for proper reading and understanding of above mentioned concepts?

Comment: Magento dev docs, mage2.tv and swiftotter study guides

Comment: @AnshuMishra, got it. I will certainly look into swiftotter, wasn't aware of it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This is thirdparty module. I assume they follow magento standard.

Open **etc/frontend/di.xml**

Find out following tag

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
```

Inside **configProviders** have one class which actually pass data to js.

[You can check magento default module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/AuthorizenetAcceptjs/etc/frontend/di.xml#L16)

and [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/AuthorizenetAcceptjs/Model/Ui/ConfigProvider.php#L45)

**[Update]**

According to getConfig() method, you should try to pass value following way:

```
$config['payment'][static::CODE]['customerName'] = $this->getCustomerName();
```

OR

```
$config = array_merge_recursive($config, [
'payment' => [
    static::CODE => [
            'useVault'                => true,
            'canSaveCard'             => $this->canSaveCard(),
            'canStoreBin'             => $this->getCanStoreBin(),
            'customerName'            => $this->getCustomerName(),
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Now this value is accessible by the following code:

```
var config=window.checkoutConfig.payment.authnetcim;

config.customerName
```

You can check all data inside console like:

```
console.log(window.checkoutConfig.payment.authnetcim);
```

Comment: I found existing custom ConfigProvider class and created new one in a module to add a new method as below, but not getting the data inside the .js function. Am I missing anything?

`$config = parent::getConfig();
$config['customerName'] = $this->getCustomerName();`
                                                                                                                                
.js file function to get above config data

`getCustomerName: function () {
 return config.customerName;
}`

Comment: var config=window.checkoutConfig.payment.authnetcim; -> This is how you get data in js

Comment: Show how you tried.

Comment: Wrote custom Model ConfigProvider.php that extends ParadoxLabs\Authnetcim\Model\ConfigProvider, then added below method

`public function getCustomerName() {
 if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
  return $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
 }
 return false;
}`

Added below code to getConfig() method:

`$config['customerName'] = $this->getCustomerName();

.js function:

`getCustomerName: function () {
 return config.customerName;
}`

Code in .html template to access customerName data

`<!-- ko if: (getCustomerName())-->`

Comment: I do see it working if I hard code a name inside the .js getCustomerName() function, so I am guessing it's an issue with getting model data into config object that is of type window.checkoutConfig.payment.authnetcim.

Comment: Can you update the question with ConfigProvider class that you modified?

Comment: updated the question with more information on the custom ConfigProvider implementation and other details.

Comment: You need to share getConfig method.

Comment: sorry, missed it earlier, updated in the question.

Comment: Check updated answer. Flash you js cache too.

Comment: @cnu if hard coded name inside the js is working then may be the reason for not working properly would be the js code to fetch the name

Comment: It appears to be some unknown issue with extending vendor ConfigProvider class since .js is not getting checkConfig data in either of above 2 approaches. I tried approach mentioned at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246902/how-to-pass-data-from-php-to-javascript-component and it's working now.